# Ionic Installation via npm

Tags: node.js, cordova, npm, ionic-framework

I am facing an error while installing cordova and ionic each and everytime. As I start my installation using npm install -g cordova ionic. The installation cursor keeps on rotating like for many minutes and then I have to explicitly terminate the installation. Please help me with this issue.

Answer (score 2):

you can try

```
npm --loglevel info install -g cordova ionic
```

and it should tell you more about what is happening / where the installation process stalls.

Answer (score 0):

try `npm install -g cordova` first followed by `npm install -g ionic`
also you may need to install other missing components if any, CLI will intimate you very nicely.

Answer (score 0):

What the command:

```
npm install -g cordova
```

ionic does is tries to install the cordova and ionic in a sequential order and -g manages the environment variables as well.

So, i recommend you to first install cordova then ionic.

```
npm install -g cordova,
npm install -g ionic,
```

Furthermore, i prefer using gitbash CLI rather than the cli provided by default.

It handles the issues of bower installation which may appear afterwards.And if you want a complete guide from installing to building an android project you can try the steps of the blog from [here](http://ionicsupport.blogspot.com/2015/12/beginners-guide-for-installation-of.html?showComment=1451365384397#c6175594702417901582.).

Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

Using cache help me to face this issue with following command :

```
npm install -g cordova ionic --cache "c:\path\to\use\as\dependencies\cache"
```